# Listen to 2 or more values in a controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a value: `$scope.loading` that is `true` when my controller is loaded.

I want to set it to `false` when I received all data from multiple sources.

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, dataFactory) {

$scope.loading = true;
$scope.gotData1 = false;
$scope.gotData2 = false;
$scope.gotData3 = false;



//Get Data 1
    dataFactory.getData1().then(function (response) {
        //...
        $scope.gotData1 = true;
    }, function (error) {
        //...
    });

//Get Data 2
    dataFactory.getData2().then(function (response) {
        //...
        $scope.gotData2 = true;
    }, function (error) {
        //...
    });

//Get Data 3
    dataFactory.getData3().then(function (response) {
        //...
        $scope.gotData3 = true;
    }, function (error) {
        //...
    });

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
$scope.loading = true;

//Get Data 1
var promise1 = dataFactory.getData1();
promise1.then(function (response) {
    //...
    $scope.gotData1 = true;
}, function (error) {
    //...
});

//Get Data 2
var promise2 = dataFactory.getData2();
promise2.then(function (response) {
    //...
    $scope.gotData2 = true;
}, function (error) {
    //...
});

//Get Data 3
var promise3 = dataFactory.getData3();
promise3.then(function (response) {
    //...
    $scope.gotData3 = true;
}, function (error) {
    //...
});

$q.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(){
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```